# failed to upgrade to pop_os! 20.04

Tags: linux

I'm trying to upgrade pop_os! from `19.10` to `20.04`.

I followed [this official guide](https://support.system76.com/articles/upgrade-pop/) but when I tried to update, this error appeared.  I do not know what it means or what should I do:

```
failed to upgrade OS: failed status: fetch of package 'libboost-date-time1.67.0_1,67.0-17ubuntus_amd64,deb at http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu poolíuniversen boost1.67/libboost-date-timet.67.0_1.67.0-17ubuntus_amd64.deb failed: async fetch for "/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/libboost-date-time 16701676170 centuem ece failed: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/boost1.67/libboost-date-time1.67.0_1.67.0-17ubuntus_amd64.deb: connection dosed before message completed
```

**Edit:** also the system is not booting.

Comment: Good question, but wrong site. I’m voting to close this question because this question is not "Programming" related it is probably better asked on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 2):

For me I needed to retry this command

`pop-upgrade release upgrade systemd`

several times and every time the number of packages to be downloaded decrease until all packages are downloaded and ready for installation.